# Paperclip, ImageMagick "UnrecognizedAlphaChannelType `remove'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I am running a project with these software versions:

1. Paperclip 4.2.0
2. Rails 4.0.4
3. RHEL 6
4. `convert -version` => ImageMagick 6.8.9-9
5. `convert -list configure` =>

   `DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg freetype jng jpeg lcms png ps tiff x zlib`

and am getting this error while processing images through Paperclip.

```
Command :: convert '/tmp/a583e7c175d537c0442da246e5184fe120141205-17371-tvp3g.jpg' -auto-orient -resize "x85" -crop "85x85+21+0" +repage -alpha remove -strip '/tmp/a583e7c175d537c0442da246e5184fe120141205-17371-tvp3g20141205-17371-1ym7alo.png'
convert: UnrecognizedAlphaChannelType `remove' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/636.
Cocaine::ExitStatusError: Command 'convert '/tmp/a583e7c175d537c0442da246e5184fe120141205-17371-tvp3g.jpg' -auto-orient -resize "x85" -crop "85x85+21+0" +repage -alpha remove -strip '/tmp/a583e7c175d537c0442da246e5184fe120141205-17371-tvp3g20141205-17371-1ym7alo.png'' returned 1. Expected 0
Here is the command output:

from /home/proj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocaine-0.5.4/lib/cocaine/command_line.rb:96:in `run'
```

This error is caught on the `Thumbnail` processor in the `make` method.

The most confusing part of this is that I set a debugger when this error is caught, copied the `src` tmpfile to a permanent location outside my project and ran the exact same `convert` command as above and it runs successfully with exit status 0.

My next step in debugging would probably to `bundle open cocaine`, but I think there is something higher level going wrong... Hoping someone has run into this before?

I don't get the same problem on OSX.

Comment: What's the output of `$ which -a convert` on the RHEL system?

Comment: Do you only have this problem with PNG files?

Comment: @JacobBudin I love you. I didn't know about the `-a` flag on `which` and didn't even think of checking for multiple installs. I think this should solve my case. I'm trying to figure out how to install the ImageMagick header files for v6.8.9, but I think this should fix this. Can you add as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have multiple installations of ImageMagick installed. You can check at the command line like so:

```
$ which -a convert
```

If you *do* have multiple installations, and Paperclip is referencing the "wrong" one, Paperclip allows you to specify the path to seek. As from the [Paperclip README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/README.md):

> In development mode, you might add this line to `config/environments/development.rb`:
>
> ```
>    Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
> ```